# Plotting stacked bar

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, stacked

[image]

The left side of the figure represents the dataset. The right side of the figure represents the sketched bar that I want to produce. how can I plot these data to produce such sketched bar where X represents age groups and Y represents Length groups?

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
random.seed(365)
data = {'age': [np.random.randint(90) for _ in range(100)],
        'length': [np.random.randint(30) for _ in range(100)]}

# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# age and days groups
df['age_group'] = pd.cut(df['age'], bins=[0, 50, 60, 70, 80, 1000], labels=['<50', '50-59', '60-69', '70-79', '≥80'])
df['days'] = pd.cut(df['length'], bins=[0, 6, 20, 1000], labels=['≤5 days', '6-20 days', '≥20 days'])

 age  length age_group       days
  72      22     70-79   ≥20 days
   2      14       <50  6-20 days
  14      12       <50  6-20 days
  47       4       <50    ≤5 days
  18      12       <50  6-20 days

# groupby plot
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))
df.groupby(['age_group', 'days'])['days'].count().unstack().apply(lambda x: x*100/sum(x), axis=1).plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(-0.05, 0.5))
plt.xlabel('Age Groups')
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['{:.0f}%'.format(x) for x in plt.gca().get_yticks()]) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

- This solution is similar to that provided by [Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang), except it provides a `y-axis` from 0% - 100% while the other is normalized from 0 - 1.
- The other solution could be used and then just format the y-axis with:

  - `plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['{:.0f}%'.format(x*100) for x in plt.gca().get_yticks()])`

Answer (score 2):

You can cut each column into respective bins and do a value count:

```
age_bins = pd.cut(df['age'], bins=[0,50,60,70,80,1000],
                  labels=['<50','50-59','60-69','70-79','80+'])
length_bins = pd.cut(df['Length'], bins=[0,5,21, np.inf],
                    labels=['<=5 days', '6-20 days', '21+ days'])

(length_bins.groupby(age_bins)
     .value_counts(normalize=True)
     .unstack()
     .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

you would get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pd.cut` to convert the continuous variable into categorical values. 
Then, calling `pd.crosstab` would get you the required information.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
age = np.random.randint(40, 90, size=(200,))
length = np.random.randint(0, 30, size=(200,))

age = pd.cut(age, bins=[0, 50, 60, 70, 80, np.inf],labels =['<50','50-59','60-69','70-79','80+'])
length = pd.cut(length, bins=[0, 5, 20, 100], labels =['<=5 days', '6-20 days','20+ days'])


df = pd.crosstab(age, length).apply(lambda row: 100*row/row.sum(),axis=1)
df.columns.name = 'Length'
df.index.name = 'Age'

ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, legend='reverse', figsize=(12, 8))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=0, labelsize=20)

ax.set_xlabel('Age', fontsize='xx-large') 

ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(-0.4, 0.5), fontsize=20)

ax.set_ylim(0,100) 
ax.set_yticklabels([f'{int(i)}%' for i in ax.get_yticks()],  fontsize=20)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.yaxis.grid(color='gray')
```

[image]